# docker 1.8 command mkdir fails when running demo python app

Tags: centos, docker

I ran this as root. The only different thing about my install is, I changed the docker dir to /opt/docker in /etc/sysconfig/docker. /opt is formatted with xfs. Kernel is 2.6.32-573.3.1.el6.x86_64. OS is CentOS 6.7.

docker run -d -p 80:5000 training/webapp python app.py
23a15587ec334df6b1a19589b47210f7034b721c8281c3b692f4ff0ab5bc12c6
Error response from daemon: Cannot start container 23a15587ec334df6b1a19589b47210f7034b721c8281c3b692f4ff0ab5bc12c6: [8] System error: mkdir /opt/docker/devicemapper/mnt/23a15587ec334df6b1a19589b47210f7034b721c8281c3b692f4ff0ab5bc12c6/rootfs/sys/fs/cgroup: no such file or directory

Comment: Then, change it back.

Comment: I changed it before I started docker. When I started the deamon for the first time, the "-g /opt/docker" was already in /etc/sysconfig/docker